# How unselect analogous value in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

i have table which has id and some array value like below:

```
|id| |column 1| |column 2| 
|1 | |18,20,21| |18,23,24| 
|2 | |188,201 | |210,230 |
```

i select some row by this SQL code:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE id =  '1'
OR column 1 like  '%18%'
OR column 2 like  '%18%'
ORDER BY id
DESC
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

but when execute this query, this code return to me both of rows it means return to me column which has 18 and column which has 188 because 18 is almost like 188 while i just need row which has only 18 not analogous value like 188 or 1888 ,... .

how can i solve this problem?

18 is variable by the way!

Comment: Fix the table structure thats not the right way to store data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE id =  '1'
OR concat(',',column1,',') like  '%,18,%'
OR concat(',',column2,',') like  '%,18,%'
ORDER BY id
DESC
LIMIT 0 , 30
```